# Mounting and unmounting temp disk using ./copykernel.sh

Tags: operating-system, filesystems, bootloader

The provided shell script copykernel.sh copies the kernel binary onto an image of a bootable floppy drive (anybody remembers floppy drives?). For this, the script first mounts the image as a floppy, then copies the binary onto the floppy, and then unmounts the image again. Now you tell bochs to boot off the floppy, which contains the bootloader and the kernel binary.
Trying to sue boche to run a kernel on my mac, need to create temp drive to copy data over and unmount it after. This is the command that are in the copykernel.sh file:

mkdir ./floppy
hdiutil attach ./dev_kernel_grub.img -mountpoint ./floppy
cp kernel.bin ./floppy
sleep 1
hdiutil detach ./floppy
rmdir ./floppy

When I run this, I keep on getting the same error:

hdiutil: attach failed - no mountable file systems
hdiutil: detach failed - No such file or directory
rmdir: ./floppy: Directory not empty

I am confused why it can't find the file system. I checked permissions, drive type, and if it is curropted or not, it all looks good. I can't seem to figure out how to fix this.